# Is there a test ack system to cope with a redelivery?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

In RabbitMQ, when setup with acks enabled, if a consumer fails its heartbeat and rabbit re-queues a piece of work that the consumer already has and is actively working on, is there built in functionality in the rabbit client (in my case C# but any would be of interest) to detect this on the consumer side?

I'm thinking either some form of event on the consumer model, or maybe a test ack mechanism that will allow detection of the message status, and that its been requeued for processing on another consumer?